# Updating a Row in Table Based on Column Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below requirement to update gwtypelist column's NULL value with table_name column if it exists in gwtypelist

```
    table_name          typecode    gwtypelist           gwtypecode
cctl_banlength_ext  13to24months    cctl_banlength_ext  13to24months
cctl_banlength_ext  25to36months    cctl_banlength_ext  25to36months
cctl_banlength_ext  37to48months    cctl_banlength_ext  37to48months
cctl_banlength_ext  49to60months    cctl_banlength_ext  49to60months
cctl_banlength_ext  6to12months     cctl_banlength_ext  6to12months
cctl_banlength_ext  lessthan6months cctl_banlength_ext  lessthan6months
cctl_banlength_ext  morethan60months       NULL         NULL
cctl_country            UK             cctl_country     UK
cctl_country        Australia             NULL          NULL
cctl_vehicle        Audi                  NULL          NULL
cctl_vehicle        Masserati             NULL          NULL
```

Output: The third column's NULL value should be populated if it's exists in the first column

```
    table_name          typecode    gwtypelist           gwtypecode
cctl_banlength_ext  13to24months    cctl_banlength_ext  13to24months
cctl_banlength_ext  25to36months    cctl_banlength_ext  25to36months
cctl_banlength_ext  37to48months    cctl_banlength_ext  37to48months
cctl_banlength_ext  49to60months    cctl_banlength_ext  49to60months
cctl_banlength_ext  6to12months     cctl_banlength_ext  6to12months
cctl_banlength_ext  lessthan6months cctl_banlength_ext  lessthan6months
cctl_banlength_ext  morethan60months cctl_banlength_ext NULL
cctl_country            UK             cctl_country     UK
cctl_country        Australia          cctl_country     NULL
cctl_vehicle        Audi                  NULL          NULL
cctl_vehicle        Masserati             NULL          NULL
```

I tried running few update queries but I was always getting the same result.

```
update #comp
set gwtypelist = table_name
where gwtypelist in (select distinct table_name from #comp)
```

Please let me know if this can be done with the update statement or for any alternatives.

Comment: Tag your question only with the database you are using.  The use of `#` in the table name suggests SQL Server.

Comment: Sure Gordon, but since it was related to just an update statement so I tagged other databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
update c
    set gwtypelist = c.table_name
    from #comp c
    where c.gwtypelist is null and
          exists (select 1 from #comp c2 where c2.gwtypelist = c.table_name);
```